# HQL query in with spring hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am very new to Spring and Hibernate and am very confused about how to select a user from user table with email. Something like this:

```
@Override
public Users authenticate(String email) {
    return (Users) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Users WHERE email = "+"'" + email +"'");
}
```

But I get this error

> .Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.procurement.bean.Users

If I try to use something like

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = '7277' ");
List list = query.list();
```

Even though I know that can't work, but am I suppose to get this error

> "Query cannot be resolved to a type"

My `Users.java`:

```
package com.procurement.bean;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class Users {

@Id
@Column(name="userId")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userId;

@Column(name="firstName")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="lastName")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Column(name="phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name="role")
private String role;

@Column(name="image")
private String image;

public Integer getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}




}
```

My DAO:

```
@Override
public Users getUserByEmail(String email) {
    return (Users) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Users.class, email);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to call uniqueResult() to get the first result and need to set the  value.

```
@Override
public Users authenticate(String email) {
    return (Users) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Users WHERE email=:email").setString("email", email).uniqueResult();
}
```

Error : org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl cannot be cast to com.procurement.bean.Users 
means you are trying to cast query instance to User object, so need to execute the query first to get the result.

Please refer the Examples :

http://www.javadocexamples.com/org/hibernate/Query/uniqueResult().html

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I was able to solve it this way

```
public Users authenticate(String email) {
    return (Users) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Users WHERE email = "+"'" + email +"'").uniqueResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the return type of your query which is `User.class`, look at my example below.

Secondly, your query makes you prone for SQL injection, use prepared statement instead.

```
Users users = session.createQuery("from Users u where u.email = :email", Users.class).setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Ok thank you for the info. pls can u share a link where i can learn spring with hibernate

Comment: For hibernate you can go to @Vlad Mihalcea blog, https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/, for Spring go have a look at http://baeldung.com